# Universal database primary key across tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, doctrine

I been searching, but I couldn't find any info on this.

How does stackoverflow or facebook generate there BIGINT id's? They are always unique across all the tables.

For example:

```
id  |   table
1       user table
2       photo table
3       feed table
4       user table <... next was 4 and not 2
```

Is there any doc on this? I don't think there will be two inserts to keep record of each table type and then assign id to the table, because that will slow the process of inserts and is really bad for performance wise too.

There are other examples to use:

https://www.percona.com/blog/2008/04/02/stored-function-to-generate-sequences/
http://devzone.zend.com/1786/mysql-sequence-generator/

Comment: id bigint auto_increment primary key

Comment: @SIDU the question is bit different. I'm asking how to have one auto_increment for all the tables.

Comment: Note that most DBMSs have table-independent sequence generators so you don't need to roll your own code to do this. MySQL is an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a global bigint as pk for all tables, you might need a seperate table just store the pk?

and insert a record into this table first to get the bigint  and then insert into member tables.

However at second thought, what is the points of benefit by doing this?

If you really want this happen, a simple solution as follwoing:

have a general study of your tables, how quick they are growing, then allocate bigint for them eg:

user_table  1,000,000 - 1,999,999
photo_table 2,000,000 - 2,999,999
...

When bigint are closer to running out, dispatch a new range for them, by simply inserting a new blank row in the table, and the bigint will auto_increased by 1 from the new bigint value

Comment: There is probably another way of doing this other then the one you mention, as I said on my post. This method can be performance issue.  The reason for doing this. On the site you can search object by the id and across all the tables it will be unique id. thats why facebook uses and even stackoverflow uses too.

Comment: Another reason for doing this is that it allows supertyping of previously distinct entity sets (e.g. customers and employees) without having to renumber existing data or tag extra info onto the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't. And wouldn't want to. You are making an assumption when you say that stackoverflow and facebook generate ids that are always unique across all tables. That is an incorrect assumption. Just because one id is used for the users table doesn't mean the same number can't be used for a totally unrelated question id in the questions table. The id is unique in the context of their own tables, but they are not forcing it to be unique across every table.

Case in point: [question 771743](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771743/) and [user 771743](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771743/) have the same id but are unrelated.

Comment: Well I'm not so much sure what tables they are using for on stackflow. but with my experience over facebook, they are definitely using it. You can try there api. just increment add value for object and different object will be pulled. sometimes its user and sometimes its photo and sometimes its feed.